# pattern best way to connect View to multiple Controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I'm recently doing a purchase order program using the MVC pattern in C# (not ASP.NET web app, just a desktop program). Now the problem is that in the UI there are lots of buttons that will link to another section, let's say from the order page I can click and go to the inventory page. Each section of course have their own set of MVC.

How can I connect the button to other controller while maintaining abstraction? That is each view does not have to understand how the other controller works, or what parameters it requires to work.

There are a couple of design possibilities that comes to mind but I have no idea which one is better / simpler:

- The dirty way: just put the references to all the required controllers in one view, but this way reduce abstraction.
- Shared view space: each button is a different view that has their own controller, but then I need to have view manager of some sort.
- Routing: pretty much like ASP. NET RedirectToAction, make a custom router that use common type (like string) to determine which controller and which action to perform
- Custom button for each action: for each controller and each action I make a button class just for it. Then I need a way for the view to supply the required parameters to each button.

Any suggestion on what should I do?

Comment: Why do your views need to reference controllers? If your views just emitted events then any controller, or controllers could listen and respond.

Comment: Then how do you register to that event? Let's say InventoryButton.Clicked += InventoryControl.ShowList (Inventory Model) how do you give InventoryControl.ShowList without knowing the reference? This or in controller OrderView.InventoryButton.Clicked += ShowList (InventoryModel) either way view and controller must know each other

Comment: Controllers typically depend on views and register for events on construction or other suitable event.

Answer (score 0):

What i think that you should for the "shared view" i.e create on shared view containing all of that buttons and their calls if this is not working for you then you can create a saprate calls of WebAPI in their controller to get your date in return.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use a modification to my 4th option, a factory pattern that creates all my buttons. The factory is given the references to all the controllers and initializes all the buttons accordingly.

The view only need this factory during construction and ask for any of the button it can produce.

This way the view doesn't need to know anything about the controller during construction. The controller also doesn't need to know the view at all.

Thanks for everyone sharing their opinion.